# SuiteCRM folder_rel table to big

Tags: database, sugarcrm, suitecrm

My "folder_rel" database in suitecrm is increasing to fast and i don't understand why... 17hours increase 2GB!

1.5G Jun 27 00:50 folders_rel
2.6G Jun 27 09:16 folders_rel
3.7G Jun 27 17:53 folders_rel

I know this folder is related to the email so i see all mail inbound configurations and delete some accounts, without any success.

There's an exemple of the table data.

`folders_rel` (`id`, `folder_id`, `polymorphic_module`, `polymorphic_id`, `deleted`) VALUES
('00000065-2fe8-e6c0-f54e-5d15f6d4f3fc', 'ed430a0c-b7b0-66bd-bc0d-4d853cb5a2e2', 'InboundEmail', 'e80003fa-4d2a-7f41-babe-4d853c1cd34c', 0),
('000003a0-fa7d-7219-642f-5d138798d52a', 'ed430a0c-b7b0-66bd-bc0d-4d853cb5a2e2', 'InboundEmail', 'e80003fa-4d2a-7f41-babe-4d853c1cd34c', 0),
('000004ce-67e6-c307-73fd-5d14ba0b7803', 'ed430a0c-b7b0-66bd-bc0d-4d853cb5a2e2', 'InboundEmail', 'e80003fa-4d2a-7f41-babe-4d853c1cd34c', 0),
('0000053d-5697-2358-df78-5d149bf337bc', 'ed430a0c-b7b0-66bd-bc0d-4d853cb5a2e2', 'InboundEmail', 'e80003fa-4d2a-7f41-babe-4d853c1cd34c', 0),
('0000085e-33b7-559f-694d-5d157f475658', 'ed430a0c-b7b0-66bd-bc0d-4d853cb5a2e2', 'InboundEmail', 'e80003fa-4d2a-7f41-babe-4d853c1cd34c', 0),
('00000c8d-97df-8a68-1030-5d1629a46f58', 'ed430a0c-b7b0-66bd-bc0d-4d853cb5a2e2', 'InboundEmail', 'e80003fa-4d2a-7f41-babe-4d853c1cd34c', 0),
('00000cc0-c85e-06f7-bdbf-5d15e32470fa', 'ed430a0c-b7b0-66bd-bc0d-4d853cb5a2e2', 'InboundEmail', 'e80003fa-4d2a-7f41-babe-4d853c1cd34c', 0);

Do you have any ideia what can cause this?

Thanks!

Comment: First I thought there is some spam incoming, but actually the lines you posted look like duplicate entries. `SELECT COUNT(0) AS cnt, folder_id, polymorphic_module, polymorphic_id, deleted FROM folders_rel GROUP BY folder_id, polymorphic_module, polymorphic_id, deleted HAVING cnt > 1;` Possibly an infinite loop running. Look for a very long running PHP process and terminate it.

Comment: any one of email listed as "Inbound Email" receiver, has been spammed!. you should stop "Inbound Emails" Job asap.

Comment: Hello everyone. Thanks for your answers. 
In fact I get some spam but it has never been a issue until now. 
What I saw was that the suite creates a note for every attachment the email contains and some email have several images, sometimes 30 images. This multiplying by 40 or 50 spam emails a day increase the DB stupidly. Thank you soo much again!